# Desktop crash on screen timeout with 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 for the first time, and my Intel-based desktop machine now crashes when the screen timeout expires, requiring a hard power-off and restart.  The behaviour was previously correct with 14.04 when any movement of the mouse or key pressed would wake the machine into the password check screen

Comment: Next time this happens write down the time. After a reboot you can inspect `/var/log/syslog` for entries relating to that time and include them in your question.

Comment: Here are syslog lines around crashes at 06:50 and 07:20.  On restart there is a system message “recovering journal” and several “clearing orphaned inode”

Apr 25 06:47:58 lynne-desktop systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Apr 25 06:51:24 lynne-desktop wpa_supplicant[836]: wlp0s11: WPA: Group rekeying completed with c8:91:f9:76:f8:3c [GTK=CCMP]
Apr 25 07:17:02 lynne-desktop CRON[2010]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Apr 25 07:21:24 lynne-desktop wpa_supplicant[834]: wlp0s11: WPA: Group rekeying completed with c8:91:f9:76:f8:3c [GTK=CCMP]

Comment: Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and moreover, after a reboot the user profile seems to be corrupted: I can still log in, but I just see the background with no unity launcher. The guest login does still work, though. 
Please let me know if you want me to add log information here - I checked /var/log/syslog, but it contains only entries from today. I've currently resolved the problem by not letting the laptop go in standby mode.

Comment: I applied the updated Linux 4.4.8 kernel as suggested, but the issue remains for my Intel-based desktop machine:  crashes when the screen timeout expires. I have to set the timeout to "never" to avoid the problem.

Comment: I repeated the "crash" which was timed at 18:55 and then forced power-off restart at 18:59 - the syslog entry before the crash is earlier:          May  1 18:21:34 lynne-desktop wpa_supplicant[809]: wlp0s11: WPA: Group rekeying completed with c8:91:f9:76:f8:3c [GTK=CCMP]

May  1 18:59:22 lynne-desktop rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="561" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"]
start